# How to take multiple variables from a previous function in Google Script / Forms?

Tags: variables, google-apps-script, google-forms

I want variables on my 1st function(sendLater) to be recognized by my 2nd function(sendMail).

My problem is that formation and lastDay aren't recognized and are defined as "null" as soon as they are in sendMail.
I don't understand how to assign vars with properties taken from the first function.

The function sendMail, where I want to take the vars from sendLater :

```
function sendMail(event) {
  var ide = event.triggerUid;
  var data = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperties();
  for (var key in data) {
  Logger.log('Key: %s, Value: %s', key, data[key]);
}
//RETURNS Key: id, Value: test@mail.fr 
//RETURNS Key: fo, Value: chosen formation
//RETURNS Key: ld, Value: yes
  Logger.log(id, fo, ld, mail, formation, lastDay); //RETURNS NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
}
```

I tried putting `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty([key], data[key]);` in the loop for every key to become the name of the var, and what they contain to become the property.
It didn't take the name of the var but takes "key" and then, says that key = the last var defined by the loop.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What is your final objective?

Comment: I want these variables to be used for the mail which will be automatically sent later. If lastday = yes, the mail is send and, in it, I want to put informations respondants wrote when they replied. Like "Hello [replyer's name], the [date], you did the formation [formation's name]" etc. 
I did Logger.log() for each one of them and they are recognized in SendLater's function, but sort as "null" in SendMail's function.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. What do you get at `event.scriptproperties`?

Comment: With Logger.log(event.scriptproperties), I got `null`.
I changed the code a little to make several properties correctly on sendLater's function. I deleted this line because it didn't make sense (I think). 

Even if it's better, sendMail's doesn't recognize them and sort all this vars defined in sendLater return as `null`.

Comment: I think the issue might be in `var id, da, jo, fo, dj = event.triggerUid;`. In my tests, I can save properties from a function and retrieve them from a different one.

Comment: I change my post a lot. I can't find how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found how to fix it. My specific problems was "How to turn arrays values into variables". I found a post that talked about destructuring assignments and searched this term on Google Script Documentation : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#destructuring_assignments

So, the final code and solution is :

```
  var data = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperties();
  var mail = data.id;
  var formation = data.fo;
  var lastDay= data.ld;
```